# Is there a way to improve the speed of the NDSolve in my code?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

[image]

I want to tell the background before raising the question of details.

My boss and I are designing synthersizer in a millimeter-wave chip. He analyzes the transient behavior with Julia. His code is amazing and the speed is super fast. After compiling, it usually takes 2 seconds around to get the transient plot. There is a special function VectorContinuousCallback being used in the ODE solving.

I did similar thing in matlab. But there was no Event can be defined in ODE solving(It seems 2023b has introduced it). I had to write all events by if-else and do loop-solving. The speed is hence horrible and it will take more than 30 minutes(partly also because of my bad coding).

So then I decided to go back to mathamatica. By reading the WhenEvent a few days, I now succeeded in analyzing the transient in mathematica. The speed is reduced to 3 minutes although still not comparable to the Julia code.
Please someone can check the code and see if it can be fine-tuned to improve the speed further.
(comment: without such high accuracy in the code, the result would be incorrect)

```
F0 = 14160000000; FREF = 40*10^6; C0 = 40*10^-12; C1 = 
360*10^-12; C2 = 20*10^-12; R1 = 14000; R2 = 1000; IP = 
60*10^-6; IN = 60*10^-6; KVCO = 300*10^6; DELAY = 5*10^-6; 
DN[n_Integer] := 360; n = 0;
NDSolve[{R1*C1*VC1'[t] + VC1[t] == VC0[t], 
R2*C2*VC2'[t] + VC2[t] == VC0[t], 
C0*VC0'[t] + C1*VC1'[t] + C2*VC2'[t] == ICP[t], \[Phi]'[t] == 
2 \[Pi]*(KVCO*VC2[t] + F0), 
VC0[0] == VC1[0] == VC2[0] == \[Phi][0] == ICP[0] == 
0, {WhenEvent[
Cos[\[Phi][t]/DN[n]] == 0 && Cos'[\[Phi][t]/DN[n]] > 0 && 
 ICP[t] == IP - IN, {ICP[t] -> -IN, n = n + 1}, 
"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation", "IntegrateEvent" -> True], 
WhenEvent[
Cos[\[Phi][t]/DN[n]] == 0 && Cos'[\[Phi][t]/DN[n]] > 0 && 
 ICP[t] == IP, {ICP[t] -> IP - IN, n = n + 1}, 
"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation", "IntegrateEvent" -> True], 
WhenEvent[
Cos[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] == 0 && 
 Cos'[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] > 0 && ICP[t] == IP - IN && 
 t >= DELAY, {ICP[t] -> IP}, "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation",
 "IntegrateEvent" -> True], 
WhenEvent[
Cos[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] == 0 && 
 Cos'[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] > 0 && ICP[t] == -IN && 
 t >= DELAY, {ICP[t] -> IP - IN}, 
"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation", 
"IntegrateEvent" -> True]}}, {VC0, VC1, VC2, \[Phi]}, {t, 0, 
30*10^-6}, DiscreteVariables -> {ICP, n, DN}, AccuracyGoal -> 30, 
PrecisionGoal -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxSteps -> 100000];
Plot[VC2[t] /. %, {t, 0, 30*10^-6}]
```

Comment: If you transform your odes to an explicit form, NDSolve(without AccuracyGoal, PrecisionGoal, MaxSteps)  evaluates in 10 seconds(Mathematica v12.2)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your plot!

Answer (score 4):

Try explicit form of your odes:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
odes = Solve[{R1*C1*VC1'[t] + VC1[t] == VC0[t],R2*C2*VC2'[t] + VC2[t] == VC0[t], C0*VC0'[t] + C1*VC1'[t] + C2*VC2'[t] == ICP[t], \[Phi]'[t] ==2 \[Pi]*(KVCO*VC2[t] + F0)}, {VC0'[t], VC1'[t], VC2'[t], \[Phi]'[t]}][[1]] /. Rule ->Equal

F0 = 14160000000; FREF = 40*10^6; C0 = 40*10^-12; C1 = 
 360*10^-12; C2 = 20*10^-12; R1 = 14000; R2 = 1000; IP = 
 60*10^-6; IN = 60*10^-6; KVCO = 300*10^6; DELAY = 5*10^-6;
DN[n_Integer] := 360; n = 0;
sol = NDSolve[{odes, 
    VC0[0] == VC1[0] == VC2[0] == \[Phi][0] == ICP[0] == 
     0, {WhenEvent[
      Cos[\[Phi][t]/DN[n]] == 0 && Cos'[\[Phi][t]/DN[n]] > 0 && 
       ICP[t] == IP - IN, {ICP[t] -> -IN, n = n + 1}, 
      "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation", "IntegrateEvent" -> True],
      WhenEvent[
      Cos[\[Phi][t]/DN[n]] == 0 && Cos'[\[Phi][t]/DN[n]] > 0 && 
       ICP[t] == IP, {ICP[t] -> IP - IN, n = n + 1}, 
      "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation", "IntegrateEvent" -> True],
      WhenEvent[
      Cos[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] == 0 && 
       Cos'[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] > 0 && ICP[t] == IP - IN && 
       t >= DELAY, {ICP[t] -> IP}, 
      "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation", "IntegrateEvent" -> True],
      WhenEvent[
      Cos[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] == 0 && 
       Cos'[2 \[Pi]*FREF*(t - DELAY)] > 0 && ICP[t] == -IN && 
       t >= DELAY, {ICP[t] -> IP - IN}, 
      "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation", 
      "IntegrateEvent" -> True]}}, {VC0, VC1, VC2, \[Phi], ICP}, {t, 
    0, 30*10^-6}, DiscreteVariables -> {ICP, n, DN} 
   (*,AccuracyGoal\[Rule]20*)(*,PrecisionGoal\[Rule]30,
   WorkingPrecision\[Rule]50*)
   (*,MaxSteps\[Rule]100000*) ];
```

`NDSolve` (without options `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal`, `MaxSteps` ) evaluates in 10seconds (Mathematica v12.2)

```
Plot[VC2[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 30*10^-6}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: nice. 10 second is fast. Julia uses LLVM compiler, which means it is compiled code vs. non compiled code in Mathematica, may be that is why its time is 2 seconds? Also different CPU would make difference,. May be OP is using a supercomputer and you are using normal PC, this will make difference also.

Comment: with `Apple M1 Max` it takes 3 seconds and Mathematica 13.1.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I don't know if the solution is correct, waiting for QP...

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann
 The plot above does not show correct answer. It shall converge to 0.8 after about 20us. Please try original code to get the correct plot first. Anyway, the new code is indeed faster. Thank you.

Comment: @metroidman Again: It would be helpful if you could show the correct  plot!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Hi, I added in my post. Sorry I don't know how to add it in the comment. Thank you for your help on my case.

Comment: @metroidman Just one idea: With dimensionless time `tau==t/(30 10^-6) ` perhaps we get an improved scaling of the odes. But I don't know how `ICP[]` would change.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann
I tried the scaling method, but it does not improve the speed. I realized In my code that the Cos[a]==0&&Cos'[a]>0 is unnecessary and can be replaced by Cos[a]>0. Even with such simplification, the speed merely changes.

Comment: @metroidman What did you try?  Has `ICP[]` to be changed, something like `ICP[tau]->(30 10^-6) ICP[t]`?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann What I did is but scale all time related parameters, e.g. FREF = 40*10^6 to FREF = 40, C2 = 20*10^-12 to C2 = 20*10^-6, so that less accuracy is needed. ICP cannot be scaled, otherwise the transfer function would change. Maybe I did not get your point on the  dimensionless time.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by improving the time to 1s.
The tricky is to define [Phi][t]/DN[n] instead of [Phi][t], so in the whenevent it is slow time varying function, no high accurarcy needed any longer.